# Simple Canvas Rectangle Interaction with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, rectangles, requestanimationframe

I am trying to teach myself the basics of the Canvas tag and Javascript interaction. In the following code, I can make the rectangle expand when I hover with "onmouseover", but it will not contract when "onmouseout".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
              return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                      function( callback ){
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                      };
            })();

            var rectWidth = 100;

            function clear() {
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.width, ctx.height);
            }

            function widenRect(){
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                clear();
                ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,rectWidth,100);
                if(rectWidth < 200){
                    rectWidth+=10;
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(widenRect);
            }

            function narrowRect(){
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                clear();
                ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,rectWidth,100);
                if(rectWidth > 100){
                    rectWidth-=10;
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(narrowRect);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" onmouseover="widenRect()" onmouseout="narrowRect()">
            Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
            <script>
                var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
                var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
                ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
                ctx.fillRect(0,0,rectWidth,100);
            </script>
        </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it works. First you need to put the requestAnimationFrame calls into the if condition because otherwise you will run into endless loops. On the other hand when contracting the canvas you need to use clearRect instead of fillRect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        window.requestAnimationFrame = (function(){
            return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
                    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                    function( callback ){
                        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
                    };
        })();

        var rectWidth = 100;

        function widenRect(){
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
            ctx.fillRect(0,0,rectWidth,100);
            if(rectWidth <= 200){
                rectWidth+=10;
                requestAnimationFrame(widenRect);
            }
        }

        function narrowRect(){
            var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
            ctx.clearRect(rectWidth,0,200 - rectWidth,100);
            if(rectWidth > 100){
                rectWidth-=10;
                requestAnimationFrame(narrowRect);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" onmouseover="widenRect()" onmouseout="narrowRect()">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    <script>
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle="#92B901";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,rectWidth,100);
    </script>
</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Edited my post. The clear function became obsolete.